# Looking for the name of a recent Christmas special

Tags: story-identification, santa-claus, holiday-special

I saw a Christmas special either last year or the year before and I'd like to watch it again this year. However, I can't remember the name.

I saw it either in the US or in New Zealand. I don't remember the channel. It was a traditionally-animated comedy and I think it was new when I saw it. The main character was an over-weight jerk who learns to care about other people. It takes place in a town inhabited by personifications of various holidays. Most of them looked human. Something happens to Santa and the main character has to deliver the presents. He decides to deliver presents to every child on Earth. I don't believe it was part of a pre-existing franchise or series.

At the end, the main character

> starts dating his old love, the female personification of Bastille Day.

Comment: Had the jerk incidentally a heart which was three times too small ?

Comment: @ThorstenS. It's not how *The Grinch Stole Christmas*. It's a much more recent work.

Comment: Ok, misremembered it.

Comment: Were the characters humans or anthropomorphized animals, etc...?
Any chance you can remember the broadcast channel? (I assume you mean in the US - if in the UK that would be helpful to know)

Comment: @NathanK.Campbell Updated.

Comment: http://www.dariawiki.org/wiki/index.php?title=Depth_Takes_a_Holiday

Comment: Closest thing I could find.

Comment: @WadCheber Nope, but thanks anyway.

Comment: If it helps, Marianne is the name of the personification of Bastille Day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the movie you're looking for is "How Murray Saved Christmas".

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_Murray_Saved_Christmas):

> The story begins in Stinky Cigars, the secret town where all the holiday characters live, from the famous (Santa and the Easter Bunny) to the obscure (Labor Day Amos and Arbor Day Aardvark). Everyone's happy in Stinky Cigars - except Murray Weiner, the grumpy owner of Murray's Holiday Diner. But when Santa is knocked out cold by an experimental toy - the Jack-in-the-Boxer - it's up to Murray to save Christmas - which he does, in a weirdly wonderful way. He even brings toys to the naughty kids!

Comment: I posted this from my mobile phone. I'll add links when I get home this afternoon.

Comment: http://porcupinesundae.com/tv-murray-saved-christmas/ mentions a "Bastille Day lady" as part of the cast.